# Doctrine - Rollback all migrations

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration

I seem to be having a bit of an odd problem with Symfony and Doctrine wherein a have a buildup of available migrations, many of which are duplicates and some aiming to perform queries of tables that no longer exist.

I'm looking to just rollback or 'remove' all of these available migrations so that I can just run a migration on a new database and everything will be how it is in my code.

Below is an example (this is just a dry-run):

```
  ++ migrating 20200103023439

     -> CREATE TABLE `user` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, username_canonical VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, email_canonical VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, enabled
 TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, salt VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, last_login DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, confirmation_token VARCHAR(180) DEFAULT NULL, password_requested_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
 roles LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)', name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D64992FC23A8 (username_canonical), UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649A0D96FBF (email_canonical), UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8
D93D649C05FB297 (confirmation_token), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE entry (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, album VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, artist VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, tracklist LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)', review LONGTEXT NOT NULL, image VARC
HAR(255) NOT NULL, timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL, author VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE tag (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE task (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE track (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB

  ++ migrated (0s)

  ++ migrating 20200103023541

     -> CREATE TABLE entry (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, album VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, artist VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, tracklist LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)', review LONGTEXT NOT NULL, image VARC
HAR(255) NOT NULL, timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL, author VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE tag (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE task (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE track (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB

  ++ migrated (0s)

  ++ migrating 20200103023707

     -> CREATE TABLE entry (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, album VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, artist VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, tracklist LONGTEXT NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)', review LONGTEXT NOT NULL, image VARC
HAR(255) NOT NULL, timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL, author VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE tag (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE task (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
     -> CREATE TABLE track (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB

  ++ migrated (0s)
```

You can see that it is trying to create several tables multiple times, when actually running this migration this, of course, results in many errors.

I have been trying to migrate some of these versions down, but even these result in SQLSTATE errors:

php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute 20200102235626 --down

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been wrapping my head around this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, silly me! Unbeknownst to me I could simply delete all of the migration PHP files within the DoctrineMigrations folder.